# Why my grid layout is too strange

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, mxml

I try to understand how work gridlayout and I'm very desapointed by the result.

Indeed, my layout doesn't apply width GridItem.

For each mx:GridRow,  GridItem total colspan is 6.

At first GridRow, I define, width in percent, but as you can see, GridItem hasn't same size even if width and colspan number are the same!

Main problem is on GridRow 1 and GridRow 2, both dropdowlist are too large!

```
    <s:VGroup id="mainContainer" width="{contentGroup.width}" height="{contentGroup.height}"  >




    <!-- partie centrale-->

    <s:VGroup  height="100%" width="100%">


        <s:BorderContainer width="100%" verticalCenter="0">
            <mx:Grid width="100%" height="100%"
                     paddingBottom="5" paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5">

                <mx:GridRow id="l1" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" width="15%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" width="35%" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbCivilCor" width="100%"
                                        prompt="" />
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" width="15%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label"  width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left" width="35%">
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbSpecCor" width="100%"
                                        prompt=""/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l2" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left" >
                        <s:TextInput id="tiNom" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left" width="100%">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiPrenom" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l3" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="4" horizontalAlign="left" width="100%">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiAdr1" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>

                </mx:GridRow>
                <mx:GridRow id="l4" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="4" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiAdr2" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l5" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiCP" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiVille" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l6" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbTypeTel1" 
                                        prompt="" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiNumTel1" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiRemTel1" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l7" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbTypeTel2" 
                                        prompt="" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiNumTel2" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiRemTel2" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l8" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiFax" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:Label text="Label" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:TextInput id="tiMail" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l9" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="3" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label tres long" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="3" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbAppelCourr" 
                                        prompt="" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>

                <mx:GridRow id="l10" width="100%">
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="3" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                        <s:Label text="Label tres long" width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="right"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                    <mx:GridItem colSpan="3" horizontalAlign="left">
                        <s:DropDownList id="cbPoliCourr" 
                                        prompt="" width="100%"/>
                    </mx:GridItem>
                </mx:GridRow>
            </mx:Grid>
        </s:BorderContainer>






        <customNavTab:IconToggleButtonBar id="tbbAction" height="6%" 
                                          dataProvider="{buttons}"
                                          itemClick="changeBbHandler(event)" labelPlacement="bottom"
                                          paddingBottom="2" selectedIndex="-1" toggleOnClick="false"
                                          horizontalAlign="center"
                                          bottom="3"
                                          width="100%"/>


    </s:VGroup>

</s:VGroup>
```

[image]

So, can you explain to me why layout isn't according my hope!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `GridItem`s are not consistent.  You can draw an imaginary line down all of the cell lines, and they need to line up, since this is a grid layout.  If in one case, you say you want a cell to be 35% and the one directly below that is set to 100%, you have a problem on your hands.  The cell widths need to be consistent if you are going to use a Grid layout... I prefer against Grid layouts for this very reason but I am confident you can solve it.

Take this approach:

`1`. Comment everything out except for your first row.  Cool!  It is laid out the way you want.

`2`. Now uncomment the second row.

Already, your layout is messed up.  Why?  Because all of the `GridItem`s in the second row have `width="100%"` set, which is inconsistent with the widths of the first row.

`3`. Set the widths to the same percents as the first row.  Also make sure to stretch the input controls inside them to 100%.

Rinse and repeat.